# Javascript Quote Calculator gives unexpected outputs

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here my HTML Code

```
   <form id="quoteform" onsubmit="return false;">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Job Calculator!</legend>
            <p>
            <label for="includecandles" class="inlinelabel">
            Width : </label>
            <input type="text" id="width" name="width" onclick="calculateTotal()" />
            </p>
            <p>
            <label class="inlinelabel" for="includeinscription">
            Height : </label>
            <input type="text" id="height" name="height" onclick="calculateTotal()" />
            </p>

            <br />

            <select id="SurfaceFinishRequired" name="SurfaceFinishRequired" onchange="calculateTotal()">

            <option value="30">Solid(S) x 30</option>
            <option value="55">Flexible (F) x 55</option>
            </select>
            <br />


            <select id="CurrentSurfaceMaterial" name="CurrentSurfaceMaterial" onchange="calculateTotal()">
            <option value="1">Plain Concrete  x 1</option>
            <option value="1.3">Aggregate  Fine 4mm deep x 1.3</option>
            <option value="1.4">Aggregate  Medium 8mm deep x 1.4</option>
            <option value="1.5">Aggregate  Deep 12mm deep x 1.5</option>
            <option value="1.6">Aggregate  Deeo 12mm deep x 1.6</option>
            </select>

            <input type="submit" value="Calculate" class="btn btn-success btn-large pull-right" />
            <div id="totalPrice"></div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Here my Javascript Code

```
function widthfunc()
{

    var width_price=0;



    width_price = document.getElementById("width").value;

    return width_price;

}

function heightfunc()
{

    var height_price=0;

    height_price = document.getElementById("height").value;

    return height_price;

}

function surfacefunc()
{

    var surface_price=0;

    var x = document.getElementById("SurfaceFinishRequired").selectedIndex;

    surface_price = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value;

    return surface_price;

}

function materialfunc()
{

    var material_price=0;



    var y = document.getElementById("CurrentSurfaceMaterial").selectedIndex;

    material_price = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[y].value;

    return material_price;

}


function calculateTotal()
{

    var quote = widthfunc() * heightfunc() * surfacefunc() * materialfunc();

    //display the result
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price is $"+quote;

}

function hideTotal()
{
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='none';
}
```

as i tested when other option selected `1` width and Height working fine and gives expected output. but if i change select option. it gives me wrong output.

as a example : width:1 * Height:1 * SurfaceFinishedRequired : 1 *  `currentSurfaceMaterial : 1.3` output is : 55. but it should be just 1.3 (1*1*1*1.3=1.3) right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
var x = document.getElementById("SurfaceFinishRequired").selectedIndex;
surface_price = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value;
```

you should use:

```
surface_price = document.getElementById("SurfaceFinishRequired").value;
```

Same goes for

```
material_price = document.getElementById("CurrentSurfaceMaterial").value;
```

Updated in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgLf2nyd/1/)

Comment: The dropdowns do not pick up the initial value, so you get `$0` until you change one or both of them. At least with OP's original way this problem did not exist

Comment: I think this one simple and easier. i used it before somehow it didnt give me output but now its working

Answer (score 1):

By the below code, you were not specifying the select element

```
document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value
```

You need to do like this so that you get the option of the correct select

```
var x = document.getElementById("SurfaceFinishRequired");

surface_price = x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;

var y = document.getElementById("CurrentSurfaceMaterial");

material_price = y.options[y.selectedIndex].value;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yf4uLdrw/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Lets start off with what the problem actually is; you are using this code in both `surfacefunc` and `materialfunc`

```
document.getElementsByTagName("option")....
```

That method will get *all* the `option` elements in the entire page, of which there are 7 in total (2 surfaces, and 5 materials).

When you change the selected index of each of your dropdowns, you retrieve the `selectedIndex` of that dropdown, but then use that index in the entire list of all options to find a value - this is never going to work.

What you need to do is be more specific about *which* options you want, you can do that by issuing the call to `getElementsByTagName` against the actual select element, rather than the whole `document`, or just use `.options[index]` to access a select elements options.

```
function materialfunc()
{
    var material_price=0;
    var elem = document.getElementById("CurrentSurfaceMaterial");

    material_price = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;

    return material_price;
}
```

And for that matter, you may as well just shorten it altogether

```
function materialfunc()
{
   return document.getElementById("CurrentSurfaceMaterial").value;
}
```

As it does exactly the same thing.

---

Another problem, is that for the text fields you're only recalculating the total `onclick`, which means only when first entering the field (assuming that is done by clicking on it and not, for example, tabbing to it). You may consider using `onchange` or `onblur` in addition.